# Allow access to url from one IP

Tags: apache, .htaccess, access-control

Trying to use htaccess to allow access to a url by one ip address only. There are a couple stackoverflow posts on the subject that I followed to no avail.

```
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.45\.6
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} http://sub.domain.com/thatThing [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.domain.com [R=307,L]
```

So my understanding of this is:
1. If the request does not come from this IP address
2. If the requested URL is http://sub.domain.com/thatthing
3. Redirect to the home page

When I test this, the page `http://sub.domain.com/thatthing` is available from any IP. I even tried proxy's to be sure. Is there some syntax thing I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match domain name in `RewriteCond` using `%{REQUEST_URI}`. Use it like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.45\.45\.6$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^thatThing / [R=307,NC,L]
```

Comment: With that code I can't get to /thatThing from `123.45.45.6`.

Comment: What is the full URL you're entering and what error are you getting? Did you clear your browser cache?

Comment: I did clear cache. The url I'm entering is sub.domain.com/thatthing and no error is coming up. It's just redirecting me to `/` regardless of what IP I'm coming from.   It's like it's disregarding the first condition

Comment: That means Apache is seeing a different IP address. You can check Apache access log for this.

Comment: For reasons I'd rather not discuss I can't open the log files. :( Is there anything else I can do? And is that a common problem that Apache sees a different IP?

Comment: Place a PHP/Perl script to know `REMOTE_ADDR` coming to Apache. In PHP it will be just `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`